# C++: Creating a Callback function of the correct type

Tags: c++, dll, callback

I am working on a wrapper to use a hardware component in python using a dll provided by the manufactuer. The DLL comes with header and lib files so it is easy to include the dll. 
As far as I understand, the compnent is used by calling the open function giving some initial parameters a callback function and some additional user data to it and then call the start method. In the following the component will deliver data by calling the callback function.

The header of the dll looks something like this:

```
#ifndef COMPONENT_DLL_INCLUDED
#define COMPONENT_DLL_INCLUDED

#pragma once

 #ifndef DYNAMIC_COMPONENT_DLL_LINKAGE

  // to allow include in C- and C++-code
  #ifndef DLL_DECLSPEC
   #ifdef __cplusplus
     #define DLL_DECLSPEC  extern "C" __declspec(dllimport)
   #else
     #define DLL_DECLSPEC  __declspec(dllimport)
   #endif
  #endif

typedef struct{
    eInformationType   type;
    eResultType        error;
    ComponentInfo      info;
}AsyncInfo;

typedef struct{                      
    BOOL         someParameter; 
    BOOL         someParameter2;
} ParamSet1;

typedef enum eType {
  UndefinedType   = 0x0,       
  Type1           = 0x1,        
  Type2           = 0x2         
} Param2;


// exported type SendAsynInformation
typedef void ( CALLBACK *SendAsyncInformation )( const AsyncInfo&, void *userInfo);

// exported functions
  DLL_DECLSPEC  eResultType COMPONENT_Open( const ParamSet1 Set1, const Param2 P2, SendAsyncInformation SendAsyncInfo, void *userInfo );
  DLL_DECLSPEC  eResultType COMPONENT_Start( void );
```

My question is, how must my callback function look like? I tried things like

```
void myCallback(AsyncInfo *Info, myGlobals *g)
{
    ...something...
}
```

and then pass this callback to the open function:

```
COMPONENT_Open(mySet1, myP2, myCallback, myVoidPtr);
```

But I always get errors like:

```
...cannot convert argument 3 from 'void (__cdecl *)(AsyncInfo *,myGlobals *)' to 'SendAsyncInformation'
```

I am rather new to C++ so most likely this is a trivial question. I tried numerous things, but I don't see how to do it right. So, what is my mistake?

Comment: The vital information to answer your question is not here - there should be a definition for the COMPONENT_Open function in one of the header files - the signature (return type and parameter types) of your callback function must be the same as the library is expecting.  The error message is telling you that the types do not match - it that is the exact error message you received, then I'm guessing the callback function might be 'void SendAsynchInfo(void);.

Comment: Use std::function<CALLBACK*(..)>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the `myCallback` as

```
void CALLBACK myCallback(const AsyncInfo&, void *userInfo)
{ ... }
```

and call the `COMPONENT_Open` as

```
COMPONENT_Open(mySet1, myP2, (SendAsyncInformation)&myCallback, myVoidPtr);
```

The `CALLBACK` keyword (or macro actually) in the function prototypes dictates the compiler what calling convention it's suppose to use, which if doesn't match could give you the exception during the stack frame cleanup time.

Since the `COMPONENT_Open` function accepts the callback as a type `SendAsyncInformation` which is a `typedef`, therefore you need to cast the address of your `myCallback` to the `SendAsyncInformation`.

Comment: `myCallback` has the same prototype as `SendAsyncInformation`, so why do you need the cast?